# Loop through entire array while excluding an item

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of items that I'd like to loop through and apply some code to, excluding one item (the clicked-on item).  I've tried using splice but I don't want to remove the array item, just skip over it.  In this case, I'm trying to remove a CSS class for each item, except the excluded one.

I've tried a few methods, using splice for one which isn't what I need.  I've also tried something like if (array[i] == 3 || (i - 1) = 2) { continue; else { .... } but can't seem to get that to work.

```
   var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       if(array[i] is the excluded one){
               skip over}
    else { $(items[i]).removeClass('class');
    }
```

No error messages, just not working as expected.

Comment: Can you include your HTML as well as your click function?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (including all **relevant** markup, event handlers, setup code, ...) that shows the actual problem.

Comment: Looks like jquery, why not something like `$('.commonClass').not(itemClass).removeClass('class')`

Comment: Can you post some code you tried that looks a bit more like it would not cause a syntax error? Your `if (array[i] == 3 || (i - 1) = 2) { continue; else { .... }` example would be better

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to know if the current item is the excluded one? Or how to skip over the item?

Comment: how to skip over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

In the following example we want to exclude "item2" *and fixed variable naming/reference*:

```js
var items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if(items[i] === "item2"){
    continue;
  }

   //$(items[i]).removeClass('class');
   document.write(items[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something similar but it wasn't giving me the result I needed.  Super clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

are the array items the id of the elements? - if so you need the id indicator ("`#`") in the code

```
$('#' + items[i]).removeClass('class')
```

**EDIT - i just noticed that your array is called"array", but in the else block you refer to it as items**

```
   var items= ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       if(items[i] is the excluded one){
               skip over}
    else { $('#' + items[i]).removeClass('class');
    }
```

I still think that there is a better way to do this - but try making the names the same and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".click").click(function(){ //When item with class click is clicked
               var items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
               var i;
               var itemid = this.id;
               for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { //go through array
                    if(items[i]==itemid){ //check if array item is the same as id of the class click
                        // Don't do anything, this is the one you clicked
                    }else{
                        $("#"+items[i]).removeClass('removeme'); // Remove class of all other with class click
                    }
               }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="item1 click removeme" id="item1">Test1</div>
<div class="item2 click removeme" id="item2">Test2</div>
<div class="item3 click removeme" id="item3">Test3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elegant way in functional programming:

```
const array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

// item to ignore
const ignore = "item2";

// use filter to keep only items which are not ignored
const newarray = array.filter((e)=> { return e !== ignore } );

// iterate over remaining
newarray.forEach((e)=> { $(e).removeClass("class"); });
```